# Does trimtosize() function works on ensureCapacity() function in ArrayList

Tags: memory, arraylist, size, trim, capacity

Suppose I have an Array List of String.
I used Function ensureCapacity() and set its capacity to 50.

But I add only 10 String Elements and rest 40 memory is wasted.

Now after that i use `trimToSize()` function.

My Question is "Does trimToSize() Function save my 40 memory."?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are talking about Java, as the Java ArrayList has those methods that you are mentioning, like [trimToSize()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#trimToSize()). And quoting from the javadoc for that method:

*Trims the capacity of this ArrayList instance to be the list's current size. An application can use this operation to minimize the storage of an ArrayList instance.*

So the answer is: yes, exactly.

But just to remember you: this will "save" you the space required 40 object references. So it doesn't really matter if you have want store strings, integers, or byte[] objects in that list.

And beyond: unless we are talking resource critical environments; such as some embedded system, you shouldn't worry too much about 40 list slots. Maybe about 100K; or 10 million slots; but not about 40.